# Group by and remove duplicates across arrays objects using JQ

Tags: json, jq

Given the [json](https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6221a05d7caf5d67835ef7bd), I need to group by key `userName` the object `userClientDetailDTOList` across all sites->buildings->floors and remove any duplicate mac addresses.

I have been able to do it using jq expression -

`[.billingDetailPerSiteDTOList[].billingDetailPerBuildingDTOList[].billingDetailsPerFloorDTOList[].userClientDetailDTOList[] ] | group_by(.userName) | map((.[0]|del(.associatedMacs)) + { associatedMacs: (map(.associatedMacs[]) | unique) })`

This groups by `userName` and also removes duplicate `macs` belonging to particular user. This results in a list as

```
[
  {
    "userName": "1",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "3:3:3:3:3:3",
      "5:5:5:5:5:5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userName": "10",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "4:4:4:4:4:4",
      "6:6:6:6:6:6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userName": "2",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "1:1:1:1:1:1",
      "2:2:2:2:2:2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userName": "3",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "2:2:2:2:2:2"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Live example](https://jqplay.org/s/0VHtRibfUN)

Questions:

1. Can the expression be simplified?
2. How do I remove duplicate mac addresses across all users? The mac address `2:2:2:2:2:2` is repeated for users `2` and `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is practically as good as it can get. If you really wanted to, you could still change

- `del(.associatedMacs)` to `{userName}` for a positive definition, and
- `(…) + {…}` to `{userName: …, associatedMacs: …}` to avoid the addition,

resulting in

```
… | map({userName: (.[0].userName), associatedMacs: (map(.associatedMacs[]) | unique)})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/84JcMALOVN)

---

As for the second question, if you treated the input as an `INDEX` on the IPs, you could mostly reuse the code from earlier (of course, the `unique` part wouldn't be necessary anymore)

```
[INDEX(…; .associatedMacs[])[]] | group_by(.userName) | map(…)
```

```json
[
  {
    "userName": "1",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "3:3:3:3:3:3",
      "5:5:5:5:5:5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userName": "10",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "4:4:4:4:4:4",
      "6:6:6:6:6:6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userName": "2",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "1:1:1:1:1:1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userName": "3",
    "associatedMacs": [
      "2:2:2:2:2:2"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OHr4K5mFIh)

Comment: Thank you. This looks good. Any thoughts on 2nd part of the question?

Comment: @arvindkgs You should define what should happen in such a case (i.e. which user should get the one remaining instance of the duplicates?).

Comment: When any duplicate mac is encountered, the mac should remain with the user with lesser devices/macs. I guess this may not be possible with `jq` and even if it is, it may make the `jq` expression unreadable. If it's not possible I will accept your answer.

Comment: @arvindkgs It is possible but, as you said, the more specific the criteria is, the more complex will be the code. The most trivial answer to my question ("any") can be implemented fairly easily.